# Problems updating Realm based on Rx listener on Realm objects

Tags: ios, swift, realm, rx-swift

I am trying to have an Rx listener detect changes to properties in various Realm entities (call them E1, E2, ...) using `Observable.from` cause a change in another (different) Realm entity (call that T). Often this works just fine, but in some causes I get nested Realm writes and a crash. This crash is happening because some of our code is of the form (pseudo code)

```
for e in E1, E2, ... {
    try realm.write {
        e.property = value
    }
}
```

Consistently, the write on the `second` entity in the list appears to trigger the `Observable.from` listener, and this leads to a nested write.

My use case is a dirty flag (e.g., [Dirty flags on Realm objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41603676/dirty-flags-on-realm-objects)) but I need that flag persisted, plus several other related fields (e.g., an update date/time) that have to be changed in T on each E1, E2, ... change.

Thoughts? Thanks.

### Update1

I'm using `Observable.from` from https://github.com/RxSwiftCommunity/RxRealm

Comment: I need to add that when one of E1, E2, ... are changed not only does T get updated, but another realm object, call it T2, also gets changed.

Comment: Realm doesn't have an `Observable.from` so why are you using that instead of the built in Realm functions for notifying and observing when working with Realm objects? [Notifications](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#notifications). Also, that dirty flag article is from 2017 and a lot has changed. There's highly granular control over Realm objects - a flag may not be needed any longer. Lastly, managed realm properties can only be modified inside a write so persisting the flag would be at the same time it's already written. Maybe some more info in the question would help.

Comment: Just added note in my question about `Observable.from`. Thank for letting me know about the Realm Notifications. I didn't know about that. Shall study that.